# Android facebook applicationID still null

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, sdk, metadata

I've followed everything on the tuturial connnecting to facebook, but I've been still getting applicationId cannot be null.

The login button:

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Android manifiest:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme.Base" >
        <activity
            android:name=".LoadingActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
                android:value="@string/app_id"/>
```

strings.xml:

```
<string name="app_id">1122************</string>
```

LoadingActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading);

        addControl();
        startLoading();
    }
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
                at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.containsKey(ConcurrentHashMap.java:911)
                at com.facebook.internal.Utility.queryAppSettings(Utility.java:825)
                at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$1.run(LoginButton.java:489)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Try one of the bundled samples with the SDK. If that works then take it from there to see what's going on

Answer (score 1):

I've just ran into the same issue, *move the meta-data line inside the **application** tag* instead the **activity** tag, otherwise the Facebook SDK won't be able to read it.